# Generating random points are so close together

Tags: c++, algorithm

I'm trying to generate a uniform gird, then selecting random points out of it. The problem is the points that are chosen are very close to each other. Here is my trial

Minmumal example : https://ideone.com/80jFm2

```
int random(int min, int max) //range : [min, max]
{
    static bool first = true;
    if (first)
    {
        srand(time(NULL)); //seeding for the first time only!
        first = false;
    }
    return min + rand() % ((max + 1) - min);
}

       jcv_point p1, p2, p3;
        p1.x = 325;
        p1.y = 239;
        p2.x = 431;
        p2.y = 448;
        p3.x = 640;
        p3.y = 685;
        float radius = 100;
        std::vector<jcv_point>  grid;
        std::vector<int> rand_nums;

        for (int i = 20; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 20; j < 1000; j++)
            {
                float x = (float)i;
                float y = (float)j;
                
                float distance1 = sqrt(pow(p1.x - x, 2) + pow(p1.y - y, 2));
                float distance2 = sqrt(pow(p2.x - x, 2) + pow(p2.y - y, 2));
                float distance3 = sqrt(pow(p3.x - x, 2) + pow(p3.y - y, 2));

                if (distance1 > radius && distance2 > radius && distance3 > radius)
                {
                    jcv_point p;
                    p.x = x;
                    p.y = y;
                    grid.push_back(p);
                    int idx = random(0, grid.size());
                    rand_nums.push_back(idx%width);

                }
            }
        }
        points = (jcv_point*)malloc(sizeof(jcv_point) * (size_t)count);

        for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
        {
            int idx = random(0, grid.size());
            points[i] = grid[rand_nums[idx]];
        }
```

Comment: This is not a [mre] - for starters you haven't shown what `random` is or what the output looks like

Comment: @UnholySheep Will write it now.

Comment: Can be simpler `static const bool first = []() { srand(time(nullptr)); return false; }();`

Comment: @UnholySheep Put the example

Comment: @273K Put an example

Comment: `min + rand()` may overflow

Comment: As for ideone, they are not very close to each other. So, what is "close" in your meaning?

Comment: @273K so it seems it's a visual c++ compiler problem, or overflow, how would I fix the overflow ?

Comment: @273K the grid is 1k*1k, if you notice the selected points are very close to each other, not in 1k*1k range

Comment: @273K it should be amplified more than that

Comment: It's hard to say with generation of only 8 points to say if there's any kind of clustering going on. Why don't you show us the output from your system rather than the output from ideone.

Answer (score 2):

In the first part of your code you have, basically:

```
// create new grid
for (x = ...)
    for (y = ...)
        // add a point to the grid
        // generate a random number between 0 and grid.size
```

So your random numbers at first will be clustered at the low end. That is, first time you generate a random number between 0 and 1. Then between 0 and 2, etc., etc. As your grid size increases, the range of the random numbers grows, but overall your distribution will be skewed towards the low end.

Not sure what the point is of generating your random numbers and storing them when you build the grid. I also don't see the point of dividing the generated random number by the width. Seems like you could get the desired effect by generating random points after the entire grid is built.

Build the grid, then generate random numbers between 0 and `grid.size`.

Comment: Thanks so much!, For the last statement that's my problem, and above is my trial. Would you please help with the algorithm :) BTW, plus one

Comment: @AhmedSaleh What, exactly, is your problem?

Comment: I would like to generate a grid of points 2D one, and select some random points out of it, with the same generating algorithm above(circles)

Comment: @AhmedSaleh It is not at all clear to me what you're trying to do. For example, what do circles have to do with anything? Your question was closed because others found it unclear and that it lacked debugging details. I suggest that you edit your question and clearly explain *in words* what you're trying to do. Include the code that you're running as well as the output from that code. Explain what you expect the output to be and how the actual output differs. Perhaps then others will re-open the question and we all will have more information on which to base helpful answers.